# Last click Event that is triggered of a session to be counted as the conversion in ga4

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, google-analytics-4

Is there any way to track the last event that is triggered on click should be counted as conversion event in GA4?

I tried checking out the gtm manager to track last click generated events but cant find one. actually I just want the last event of a session to be tracked.